# How to stop grunt compass task compiling sass files intended for include

Tags: css, sass, gruntjs, yeoman

In my Gruntfile.js I have this configuration for compass

```
watch: {
  compass: {
    files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
    tasks: ['compass']
  },
  livereload: {
    files: [
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/{,*/}*.html',
      '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/styles/{,*/}*.css',
      '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
      '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.json',
      '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}'
    ],
    tasks: ['livereload']
  }
},

... more stuff ...

compass: {
  options: {
    sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    cssDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
    imagesDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
    javascriptsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts',
    fontsDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/fonts',
    importPath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/components',
    relativeAssets: true
  },
  dist: {
  },
  server: {
    options: {
      debugInfo: true
    }
  }
},
```

I have started separating out my sass files, and have some files only intended to be included in the final compiled file. They rely on things previously imported, so can not be compiled on their own. How can I instruct compass, in grunt, to only compile the one root scss file, which already compiles perfectly, with all the component parts, and not to litter the directory with useless extra css files?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Prepend them with [underscore](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials) or use the [specify](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-compass#specify) option:

> Lets you specify which files you want to compile. Useful if you don't want to compile the whole folder. Globbing supported. Ignores filenames starting with underscore. Files must be in the directory you specified in `sassDir`.

Comment: can you add a link to this info?

Comment: added a couple of links.